# Libname remote library

Tags: sas

I have a SAS deployed on the unix server X and the unix server Y where some library containing SAS datasets exists.
Using SAS Enterprise Guide 7.11 connected to metadata server located on server X how can I access to datasets located on server Y?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways.

If Y is running SAS Share, you can set up a Share Library on Y and connect to it from X.  See the documentation on how to do so http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/shrref/64803/HTML/default/viewer.htm#titlepage.htm

If your system's admins allow it, create a share on Y and connect to it from X.  Then the files look like they are on the X file system and you create a library as normal.  The how is outside by area, but a competent admin should be able to do it.

Copy the data sets from Y to X using FTP/SCP/etc.